# Output content to the_content before a plugin does

Tags: plugins, filters, the-content

I'm using a plugin that appends to `the_content()` at a priority of `100`. I want to place some content after the main content but before this plugin outputs. I assumed if I use a priority less than `100` that it will come before the plugin, but the plugin is always outputting before my extra content.

My code looks like this

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_single_post_extra', 10);
function my_single_post_extra($content) {
    if(is_singular('post')) {
        $content = $content . '<p>Extra content</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

The plugin is appending like follows:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'fbcommentbox', 100);
function fbcommentbox($content) {
    $content .= '<p>plugin content here</p>';
    return $content;
}
```

I was under the impression that by using a lower priority than a plugin, that I could get my content to output before its content. Is that not correct? How would I fix this issue?

Comment: sorry but what is actually the issue? It sound lie you do not fully understand how the plugin work and except for suggesting doing some more debuggin i am not sure what anyone will be able to say about it.... maybe some other filter changes the content even before that filter, or th plugin remove all other filters on `the_content`.... there are several options that may explain what you see

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question. I outputted `$wp_filter` for the `the_content` hook and was able to see what was being output at the same time. You could put this as an answer as it may help someone else.

Comment: since it is kinda low quality question, probably better to just delete it

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Mark Kaplan's comment led the OP to the proper solution.

But it would be nice for the OP to post his solution as the correct answer, to help others that might have a similar problem.

(Spelunking unanswered questions....)